# What is the benefit of commenting the answer?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I see people simply commenting the correct answer on the question itself when they have an opportunity to provide it as an answer.

Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Yes. Please look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896097/nothing-displaying-in-console-when-using-console-log-with-if-statements-in-for-l/34896221#34896221

Comment: Most of "typo" questions are off-topic and comments are the only proper way of answering them IMO. Upvoted comments won't prevent the question from being [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/260312).

Comment: I often comment when I don't have time to answer. Hopefully someone will flesh out my comment to a full answer.

Comment: This kind of Q+A is a horrible link trap.  Another programmer is going to look at it because his search keywords happened to match the question by accident.  And it is *utterly* useless to solve his problem, another minute of his life wasted.  You would not want this to happen to you, don't make it happen to somebody else.  Flag a moderator and ask your post to be deleted so we can get rid of the Q+A.

Comment: In many cases, I canot be sure that some problem I see in the posted code is actually the cause of the OP's problem/s, as described - only the OP can be sure, after fixing and testing.   An answer is inappropriate.  Inaction is inappropriate. So...  comment.

Comment: Because they have the correct answer but don't want to take the time to flesh it out into a substantial answer instead of a one-sentence nothingburger.

Comment: I will answer a question in a comment if I want to point the asker in the right direction but don't want to spend 5-10 minutes writing up a detailed answer with full code and examples. Another scenario where I'd leave a comment is if I think I know the answer but am not 100% sure, so leaving an actual answer would possibly be inaccurate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes you do want to help OP but you know the answer won't help others since it's very specific for OP (for example *typo*s).

In this case, the question should be closed for the reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that *can no longer be reproduced* or a simple *typographical error*. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Often times OP hasn't completly clarified the question so that people feel comfortable giving a complete and definitive answer. Instead then people (waiting for the OP to clarify further) make suggestions, recommend approaches, etc. All in comments, because a full answer would be inappropiate for that. Sometimes one of these "Shots into the dark" will hit, and there is a comment that will then be the correct answer. Often times people don't care enough to finalize it.

Another reason is simple questions. Like when you see a question and you absolutely know its gonna be closed as unclear/offtopic/too broad/etc but you still want to help OP since its very easy to see what they did wrong.